# Selenium: click to button

Tags: python, selenium

It's a part of `html`-code of page, where I should click the button

```
<div class="add-company-form__form-control add-company-form__submit">
    <button class="button button_theme_islands button_size_xl button_view_action button_type_submit button__control i-bem" data-bem='{"button":{}}' role="button" type="submit">
        <span class="button__text">Добавить организацию</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I try to click on the button with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='add-company-form__submit']/button").click()
```

but it returns

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='add-company-form__submit']/button"}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @QHarr it's not unique on the page

Comment: can it be that it's in an iFrame?

Comment: The problem is that your XPath is not correct. You have `@class='add-company-form__submit'` but in fact the class has more than class name, `class="add-company-form__form-control add-company-form__submit"`. You can change it to `//div[@class='add-company-form__form-control add-company-form__submit']/button` or probably even `//span[.='Добавить организацию']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try instantiating a WebDriver wait before clicking the button:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button button_theme_islands button_size_xl button_view_action button_type_submit button__control i-bem']"));
```

NOTE:

I used Java syntax, but it should be very similar in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Try following Xpath.

```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button button_theme_islands button_size_xl button_view_action button_type_submit button__control i-bem']")))
```

If you want to use CssSelector try this.

```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button_theme_islands")))
```